# Header and Source file problems in Code::Blocks

Tags: c, file, header

I am programming a game in C using [Code::Blocks](http://codeblocks.org/). I am using the most recent version of C and of Code::Blocks. I am still learning the language.

All of my past programs have been contained in one huge source file, so I decided to branch out and try putting my code in multiple files. I know that the proper way to do it is to have source files containing code definitions and such and a header file containing prototypes for other source files to use. This has worked out horribly for me and I either can't get the files to work together properly or it simply doesn't work period.

I have a single function in a source file called `process.c` and a function prototype in a file called `process.h`. I also have a `main.h` and a `main.c` containing all the rest of the code. The main issue is that I have a `typedef struct Game` in my `main.h` file and I can't get the 'Game' struct type I created to work in my `process.c`. Every function in my game needs the `Game` type in order to work. However, when I give `process.c` access to `main.h` (the file that `Game` is declared in) I get issues.

My code works fine when it's in one file. My header files are protected from duplication and are properly included in the program. The problem is, I need to include `main.h` in both `main.c` and `process.c`. And I have to include `process.h` in both 'main.c' and 'process.c'. I have tried every configuration and nothing works.

In some `#include` configurations I get no errors, but I get this weird message that says "It seems your project has not been built yet; would you like to build it now?" and when I click "Yes" nothing happens.

My compiler works fine and there is nothing wrong with the projects settings. What the heck is going on here? How do I get `main.h` and `process.h` to work together?

*EDIT*:  Source code:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "process.h"

void initGame(Game *thisGame)
{
  variable = 10;
  number = 5;
  letter = 'c';
}

int main()
{
Game thisGame;
initGame(&thisGame);
displayData(&thisGame);
return 0;
}
```

main.h:

```
#ifndef _MAIN_H_ 
#define _MAIN_H_

typedef struct
{
int variable, number;
char letter;
}

#endif
```

process.c:

```
#include <stdio.h> //not sure if this should be here or not, it doesn't seem to effect my code
#include "main.h"
#include "process.h"

void displayData(Game *thisGame)
{
printf("%i, %i, %c", thisGame.variable, thisGame.number, thisGame.letter);
}
```

process.h:

```
#ifndef _MAIN_H_ 
#define _MAIN_H_

void displayData(Game *thisGame);

#endif
```

#### Error message

```
-------------- Build: Debug in FishKiller (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -L..\deps\lib -L..\SDLFILES\lib -o bin\Debug\FishKiller.exe obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\process.o  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  -lSDL2_image  
obj\Debug\process.o:process.c:(.rdata+0x0): multiple definition of `SCREEN_WIDTH'
obj\Debug\main.o:main.c:(.rdata+0x0): first defined here
obj\Debug\process.o:process.c:(.rdata+0x4): multiple definition of `SCREEN_HEIGHT'
obj\Debug\main.o:main.c:(.rdata+0x4): first defined here
obj\Debug\process.o:process.c:(.rdata+0x8): multiple definition of `GAMESTATE_MENU'
obj\Debug\main.o:main.c:(.rdata+0x8): first defined here
obj\Debug\process.o:process.c:(.rdata+0xc): multiple definition of `GAMESTATE_GAME'
obj\Debug\main.o:main.c:(.rdata+0xc): first defined here
obj\Debug\process.o:process.c:(.rdata+0x10): multiple definition of `GAMESTATE_GAMEOVER'
obj\Debug\main.o:main.c:(.rdata+0x10): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: From what you have described it does not sound like you have visibility issues.  You have basic _using the development environment problems_.  Starting with the basics: can you get a simple hello world program to work? `int main(void){printf("hello world!");return 0;}`  You indicated you are using _Code::Blocks_.  What compiler are you using with it?  Are you building a console app, a library,.., what?

Comment: Yes a hello world program works fine. GCC compiler. I can get the program to work if I don't use the process.c file and just define the function in the process.h file.

Comment: I edited your post with source code you provided in an answer. Typically the original post is where content like that belongs. I also created an answer with file by file comments on issues I saw in your source .

Comment: Note that the error messages seem to refer to variables rather than functions.  You declare variables in header(s) with `extern` in front.  You define the variables in one source file that also includes the header(s) for cross-checking.  Personally, I declare the functions in headers with `extern` in front for symmetry with those rare global variables that have to be declared thus — many (probably most) people disagree with me on that.

Comment: Good news: I got it to work. All I had to do was change three constant ints I had declared in the mina.h file into #define constants. Thank you Jonathen Leffler and ryyker for helping me with this issue, I am amazed at how fast I was able to find the answer I needed on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Issues are addressed file by file below.  Once these issues are corrected in your source, the executable will build.

***1)***
In process.h you have the wrong header blocks:

```
#ifndef _MAIN_H_ 
#define _MAIN_H_
//Change to:
#ifndef _PROCESS_H_ 
#define _PROCESS_H_
```

Also change:

```
void displayData(Game *thisGame);(see notes in main.h for explanation)
```

To:

```
void displayData(GAME *thisGame);
```

***2)*** In process.c you have;

```
#include "main.h"
```

It does not hurt anything, but since we are analyzing everything, it is not needed to support current architecture.

You also have:

```
printf("%i, %i, %c", thisGame.variable, thisGame.number, thisGame.letter);
```

Because the `thisGame` is passed in as a pointer, you need to use struct pointer operator: `->`

```
printf("%i, %i, %c", thisGame->variable, thisGame->number, thisGame->letter);
```

Also, the function protocol in the same file is incorrect.  You are attempting to instantiate a variable type that does not exist: (see notes for main.h)
Change:

```
void displayData(Game *thisGame){...}
```

To:

```
void displayData(GAME *thisGame){...}//uses typedef struct GAME
```

***3)*** in main.h you have a malformed struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    int variable, number;
    char letter;
}//no ";" statement terminator to indicate to your compiler _end of struct_
```

And with this definition, there is no struct *name* with which to reference or instantiate it in any other file.  Change it to the following:

```
typedef struct
{
    int variable;
    int number;//style point , put each member on its own line
    char letter;
}GAME;//note struct type name and terminator ";"
```

With the struct type name, in this case GAME, you can create instances of this struct in any file that `#includes` this file.

```
extern GAME Game;// using the extern modifier, create an instance of GAME  
                 // that can be referenced in any file of the
                 //project, once initialized.  (See the line GAME Game; in main.c)
```

***4)*** in main.c you have variables in the function `initGame` that need to be referenced differently.  Change this:

```
void initGame(Game *thisGame)
{
  variable = 10;
  number = 5;
  letter = 'c';
}
```

To:

```
void initGame(GAME *thisGame)
{
  thisGame->variable = 10;
  thisGame->number = 5;
  thisGame->letter = 'c';
}
```

There is *[Code::Blocks information here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/FAQ-Compiling_%28errors%29)* that may help you to set up your environment to get the error messages that will help you to debug your code.